# Representing Sequence Diagram for an ERP system

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want to model sequence diagram for my **ERP System** that has twelve modules as follows:

CRM
  HRM
  SRM
  Order Management
  invoicing
  reports generation
  POS
  accounts management
  Inventory
  Material management
  Warranty claim

How to address/breakdown inter-module relationship and represent them in terms of sequence diagram?

Comment: You cannot cover a complete system in a single diagram. Even a single diagram for each module will also be heavy. Create multiple diagrams, one for each flow.

Comment: Maybe could you ask the question in another way: why do you want to draw sequences diagrams ? If it is to model how your system uses the ERP, I would start from use cases, I am not sure that you can draw sequences diagram without a functional issue to address. If the goal of your question is to know how ERP modules call each others,
considering the amount of diagrams you will have to draw and their complexity, you won't have the answer.

Comment: yes Ponmudi VN, i have drawn multiple for each module but some of my friends suggest me to convert them in a single diagram

Comment: Tell your friends they should go and read a couple of books before telling such nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sequence diagram** has a ***higher granularity*** than component or deployment diagram.

So if you want to represent your system in one single diagram, I would suggest going with **a component diagram** instead of ***the sequence diagram.***

> **Sequence diagram** represents communication flow between objects in
>   terms of messages which are more granular compared to each module in
>   your system.

Each module of your system will have multiple sequence diagram and representing entire system would be a too much complicated. UML diagrams are to represent the system in a most simpler way.

I hope this answers your question.

Thanks.